# What will cause an embedded ruby code not to execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie in ruby. I just started learning about embedded ruby code in the .html.erb file. The embedded ruby code doesnt get executed. It displays the embedded ruby code as it is in the editor.
Example,

`<%= Time.now %>` instead of displaying the system's current time displays `<%= Time.now %>`

What could be the problem? Please help!!!

Comment: did you name your file as name.html.erb?

Comment: That might be a silly question, but how do you open the page? Are you using rails?

Comment: @BroiSatse, Yes am using rails. Working in aptana studio 3. Am able to open the page. Other components like labels and links work perfect. I only have a problem with the embedded ruby

Comment: @devanand, I named the file hello.html.erb

Comment: how to you call the template in your controller?

Comment: @user3218764 Just to be 100% percent sure - your local server is running and you are accessing the page via `localhost:3000` or similar?